# Tooltip flickering.

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0, tooltip, flicker

I have a waveform of an audio file. At the end of the waveform I want to display some text  in the area 50 pixels before the end of the waveform, in the tooptip. I want the tooltip to be shown only in the area which lies from 50 pixels before the end of waveform to the end of the waveform. I have written some code but it causes the flickering of the tooltip i.e. as and when i move the mouse the tooltip keeps appearing. Please help to stop the flickering.
The code is:

```
private void Waveform_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bool IsMatching = false;
    ToolTip tooltip1 = new ToolTip();
    if (e.X <= this.Width && e.X >= this.Width - 50)
    {
       tooltip1.Show("end here", this, e.X, e.Y);
       IsMatching = true;
    }

   if(!IsMatching)
       tooltip1.Hide(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `tooltip1` at the form instead of creating a new instance whenever mouse move, also when you create a new instance every time, when you are calling `tooltip1.Hide()` you are not hiding the old tool tip, you are hiding the newly created one "which is already not shown..".

Also consider setting the form [DoubleBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c.aspx) to `true`, it is used to reduce the flicker.

Comment: This solved my problem of flickering. Thanks! But now wherever i keep the tooltip on the waveform it is showing the tooltip there. it should only be shown in the 50 pixels area.

Comment: And i guess the flickering was solved by storing the mousemove (x,y) any time the tooltip is shown. Displaying tooltip in a mouse event immediately causes a subsequent mousemove event even if mouse does not move in between. You probably solved the issue by testing against saved (x,y) in the mousemove event and prevented repeating another display attempt and broke the otherwise ever repeating cycle?